# Wordpress - login page even if already logged in?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, registration

Why Wordpress shows login form even if users are already loggeed in?

If I've logged in and I go to "wp-login.php", it shows login form.
Same problem if I go to "wp-login.php?action=register", it shows register form.

How can I redirect to dashboard if users are logged in and they try to open again login or register pages?

Comment: That's default WordPress. Take a look at the actual php file, and you'll understand why there's no redirect happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding /wp-admin or /admin instead of /wp-login.php to your URL.

So for accessing the backend it would always be http://example.com/wp-admin or http://example.com/admin.

If you'r not logged in so far, it would redirect you for login.
If you already are, you will be redirected to the backend.